# How to create Image with custom text in php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, gd

I am looking to create a Product customization tool in PHP. This tool will allow the user to create his own Customization to a predefined Mobile cover. I already have a Mobile cover image and I am looking to allow a user to write 3 characters which will be written in a circle called as monogram with a background color.

I am not sure how to proceed ahead with it. I am looking to dynamically create image that is placed on the Mobile cover in such way that it looks its part.

here is the link to a sample image which would be generated

http://d13eowy7ljcd3.cloudfront.net/images/ark.png

I am looking for way on how to approach it and which php image handling libraries should I make use of.

Comment: This is going to be tough or impossible using only GD. I'd look into ImageMagick, althogh I can't think of a way to do this straight away even there. See whether one of the hundreds of examples in http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/ goes in the right direction... (namely the "distortion" chapter)

Comment: My advice would be to create a custom font with the text pre-shaped to fit your circular design.  It's damnably difficult to do this sort of thing automatically and it won't look good.  People will be paying you for your design skills not your programming anyway...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use ImageMagick: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php This need that imagemagick was installed on the system, If you do not have a dedicated server you could try with GD https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php, but I think that imagemagick is more powerfull.